# How to Extract Specific <div> Tags from Get Response?

Tags: android, dom, httprequest

I made a get request and store the response in a String `response`:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
String getURL = "some_url_with_param_values";
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();   
String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
```

But I am only interested in the `<div>`s that has the class name `<div class="product-data">`. So, I did this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
InputSource is;
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("product-data"); //I even tried: (div class="product-data)
String test = list.item(0).getNodeValue(); //Just to test it
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

---

My response string is basically an html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html .....
<html>
<head>
    //some script tags
</head>
<body>
    //some tags
    <div class="product-data">
        //some other tags
    </div>
    //some tags
    <div class="product-data">
        //some other tags
    </div>
    ....
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You know that `getElementsByTagName` gets the *tag* name, like `div`, right? Not the `name` attribute.

Comment: Right. The problem is that there are other `<div>`s in the document that I don't want. I need the one with this class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try using `getElementsByClassName('product-data')`

If that doesn't work you could always check [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), it provides an library which gives an easy way of extracting Html elements from a webpage

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);

String content = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Elements ele = doc.select("div.classname");
```

This example executes an Http GET and then extracts all Div elements with the class "classname" which you can then do what you like with

Comment: There is no `getElementsByClassName()` in the [Document doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html). I think you mixed it with Javascript Document. Jsoup sounds promising. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, I've used JS but not the Document interface, so I assumed that the same functions was present in both.

Comment: @Zyber Did you import some sort of Apache .jar into this project? I don't seem to have `DefaultHttpClient` stock.